# "insert into $schoolname ('cat','...) The $_POST " if  statement " is not passing values into $schoolname  table

Tags: php, mysql, variables, post, insert

I'm having problems getting $schoolname to read in the "insert into" mysqlcommand.

I'm just creating a small thing for a fan club that spans a few schools. So i created a different database table for each school. Each school has a unique id, and the table name corresponds to that.  The code is below. Please help. Well, the problem area is the insert portion.

"insert into $schoolname ('cat','...)
For some reason $schoolname is not catching with the $_POST if statement

the mysql command " insert into .... " passes  values if i specify a hard coded table name, but it does not pass values if i specify the variable ($schoolname) in place of the table name. I need to specify the variable because there a number of schools with each having their own tables.

```
    <?php
    require_once('include.php');
    include('imageupload.php');

$schoolid='';
if(isset($_GET['schoolid']) && isset($_GET['schoolid']) != '')
{
    $schoolid .= 'and id ='.$_GET['schoolid'];
}

$sqlschoolid = "select * from schools where status = 'Active' ".$schoolid;
$resschoolid = $obj->sql_query($sqlschoolid);
$school = $resschoolid[0];

$schoolname = $school['parameter'];
$schoolid2 = $school['id'];

    if($_POST)


{


    (isset($_POST['pr']) && $_POST['pr'] != "") ? $price=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pr']) :  $pr="" ;

    $sqlclass = "insert into $schoolname(`category`,`type`,`price`,`title`,`description`,`weburl`,`image`,`email`,`phone`,`address`,`city`,`state`,`zip`,`postdate`,`sponser`,`status`) 
    values('".$_POST['subcategory']."','".$_POST['type']."','".$pr."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weburl'])."','".$imagename."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zip'])."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."','0','Active')";


    }

    ?>
```

Comment: "I'm having problems" - more specifically?

Comment: different database per school, or different table per school?

Comment: Just as a side note, you should escape $_POST['subcategory'] and $_POST['type'] even if this is automatically filled by your HTML. People could easily change that values and make an SQL injection.

Comment: Try not only write question, but read it by yourself first. You question explain NOTHING

Comment: sorry i'm a beginner, getting a few codes patched together and learning along

Comment: we will help, but yes we have standards :)  so can you expand on "is not catching".  What do you mean?  The value is not being passed? it's nil? its null?  people need the exact details and for them to be correct to choose from the millions of permutations of answers. Thanks!

Comment: btw I made that the title as the previous one wasn't good.

Comment: Yes, the value is not going through to the corresponding table, i.e., $schoolname's value is not being echoed

I don't know if it is because $schoolname exist as a variable outside of the if $_POST statement and hence not being read.

I made $schoolname into a variable, so that based on the schoolid based on the url (with the $_GET array), I can get the school name which is the same name as that of the table.

Comment: Thank you for the adjustment. I was gonna adjust to the title, to null values being passed into mysql table. But I'll leave it the way you have it if that is better.

Comment: the mysql command " insert into .... " passes  values if i specify a table name, but it does not pass values if i special the variable ($schoolname) in place of the table name

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't specified what problem you're seeing, this is only a guess:

```
if(isset($_GET['schoolid']) && isset($_GET['schoolid']) != '')
```

Shouldn't that be

```
if(isset($_GET['schoolid']) && $_GET['schoolid'] != '')
```

As a side note, consider what happens if the user entered the following in `schoolid`:

```
0; delete from schools
```

This is known as SQL Injection, and you should be using "bind variables" instead of building the query by concatenating strings.

Comment: I have added more details. I'll go read up on bind variables. But in my include file, I have used the mysql_real_escape characteristics for the $_GET and $_POST. Will that cover that problem u cited?

The problem is with the insert portion and $schoolname for the table name i.e. insert into  $schoolname

Comment: I figured how to solve it. The $schoolname would not execute in the "if (_$POST) " statement, so i created it in a separate file and used the include. Now everything works and reads fine. 

Thank you Ladies and gentlemen. Now time to go do some SQL Injection protections. Any tips?

Comment: **Edit** Actually it still doesn't work. For some reason, it has problems executing the $schoolname within the $_POST statement. A form points to that post statement

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the below query:

```
$sqlschoolid = "select * from schools where status = 'Active' ".$schoolid;
```

<s>What is $schoolid variable at the end?</s> I see what is $schoolid variable and I assume that the variable isn't set correctly.

From what I understand is that the above query might be throwing an error and therefore $schoolname isn't populated at all. Can you please try to print how that query looks like?

**EDIT 1** Reading the past discussions, it is clear that `$schoolname` variable is empty, i.e. has no value. It is not the scope issue because from your code `$schoolname` is in the global scope and is therefore available inside the $_POST IF check. So let us try to debug the code to analyse options:

1. Can you put an `echo $sqlschoolid;` just after where you have written the query? This will confirm that the query format is correct
2. Assuming that the query is good, let us now check if the query is returning the right data? I'm not sure what DB class are you using, so I can't say what does $obj->sql_query() returns? Perhaps the MySQL resultset. Anyways, can you put `var_dump($resschoolid)` right after where it is initialized? And another `var_dump($school)` below?

This is how I would like you to put the debug statements:

```
$sqlschoolid = "select * from schools where status = 'Active' ".$schoolid;
echo $sqlschoolid;
$resschoolid = $obj->sql_query($sqlschoolid);
var_dump($resschoolid);
$school = $resschoolid[0];
var_dump($school);

$schoolname = $school['parameter'];
$schoolid2 = $school['id'];
```

I hope the above will give more insight into the problem. Let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: I can echo it ($schoolname and $sqlschoolid) just fine when I do above the $_POST  if statement. But when i try to echo it within the $_POST statement, it is not there. There is no read out. So it appears that my variable doesn't go through into the $_POST if statement.

Comment: When I print $schoolname, it says arrayschoolname .

Comment: My issue is that in another file, in the select portion, $schoolname executes but there is no $_POST if statement (no form). Here is how that looks like 


    $sqllisting="select * from $schoolname where status =  'Active'".$where.' order by sponser desc, postdate desc'.$max;
 $reslisting = $obj->sql_query($sqllisting);

Comment: this site seems to have a solution for my problem 

http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/8905-using-a-php-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-query/

Comment: @BigFreeze, sorry for my late response. I've edited my response and was wondering if you would be able to do those code tweaks and then show us the output that it throws, perhaps in your original question?